# Armageddon: Does / Should White have a lower advantage in chess960 compared to chess?

Tags: tournament, statistics, time-control, chess960, armageddon

I'm not (necessarily) asking which colour is more favoured in armageddon chess960. I'm asking that [given however much or little white has an advantage of armageddon chess](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/7962/which-side-has-the-advantage-in-an-armageddon-tiebreak-game), is this [advantage lower](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/22827/are-there-statistics-on-the-results-of-armageddon-games-at-the-gm-level) in armageddon chess960? (But if you can provably show that Black is more favoured in armageddon chess960 and White is more favoured in armageddon chess, then a fortiori White is less favoured in armageddon chess960 compared to armageddon chess.)

I think White has a lower advantage, at least in the no bid 5min vs 4min case. I mean, [there's no theory](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/37673/why-dont-these-statistics-disprove-whites-supposed-larger-practical-advanta). There's just extra time vs draw odds in chess960 while in chess there's extra time **+ theory** vs draw odds.

What have players said about this? What are some statistics?

Comment: I somewhere read that 960 tends to be more unbalanced than chess, even with some stats, but can't quote a reliable source.

Comment: @HaukeReddmann https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/37673/why-dont-these-statistics-disprove-whites-supposed-larger-practical-advanta ?

Comment: Yup, THX, that was it :-)

Comment: @HaukeReddmann oh just to clarify this post is about armageddon. i mistakenly didn't say that in the title at 1st.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## I. What players have said:

1. [Fabi says](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hmQDdnRXuBg) the white advantage is lower. But Fabi's answer might assume the players don't bid and are under
2. [Danya says the white advantage is lower. Robert Hess doesn't seem to disagree but prefers White in chess960 (as in chess?).](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MiianDlRADk) Their answers are dependent on that the players [bid](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41525/how-is-armageddon-in-chess-like-fair-cake-cutting-in-game-theory) in the 15min vs X min case (where X is the lower bid). Robert's answer also depends on that the armageddon has no increment ([as usual?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41576/is-armageddon-always-without-increment-should-it-be)).

---

## II. Statistics:

[Black wins more](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41534/what-were-all-the-chess960-armageddon-games-played-in-st-louis-chess-9lx-and-the) based on the 2019 & 2022 WFRCC and the 2022 St Louis Chess 9LX. White win rate is only 1/3.

Total games: 9

- White wins: 3
- Black wins normally: 4
- Black wins by draw odds: 2

If the [analogous win rate for white is 50%](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/22827/are-there-statistics-on-the-results-of-armageddon-games-at-the-gm-level/27203#27203), then white definitely has a lower advantage, namely 1/3 lower because -1/3=(1/3-1/2)/(1/2).

But these aren't necessarily meaningful statistics because (besides the low sample size) they aren't quite with the same amount of time because some had bidding.

As pointed out by GeneM [here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/7962/which-side-has-the-advantage-in-an-armageddon-tiebreak-game/8269#8269)

> Armageddon Chess is a *fair* tie-break system only if the two players *bid* for how much time Black should have.

For predetermined 5min vs 4min, white win rate is only 20%.

Total games: 5

- White wins: 1
- Black wins normally: 3
- Black wins by draw odds: 1

Putting aside the obvious elephant in the room of low sample size, if the [analogous win rate for white in chess *for 5min vs 4min* is 50%](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/22827/are-there-statistics-on-the-results-of-armageddon-games-at-the-gm-level/27203#27203), then white definitely has a lower advantage, namely 60% lower because -60% = (1/5-1/2)/(1/2).

Also we could look at the bid only games to see if there might be cause to have a [Vickrey auction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vickrey_auction) instead of a [blind auction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-price_sealed-bid_auction).

For bid, white win rate is exactly 50%.

Total games: 4

- White wins: 2
- Black wins normally: 1
- Black wins by draw odds: 1

Of course the sample size is low, but there's no a posteriori evidence here that shows a [need for a Vickrey auction](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41579/is-armageddon-more-fair-in-vickrey-auction-eg-magnus-hikaru-bid-858-vs-859) or something.

---

## III. Comparing winning bids:

I guess it doesn't matter if it's chess or chess960 if the players bid even if the [auction is unfair](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41575/is-armageddon-more-fair-if-bids-arent-1-time-only), but I think one's bid might change depending on chess or chess960. Eg You'd want black (or [white](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41552/why-would-i-bid-for-white-in-armageddon-in-regular-chess)) **all the more** in chess compared to chess960 because in chess there's theory (theory helps both white and black I guess) and [**more draws if you get black**](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/34723/winning-percentage-white-win-draw-black-win-in-chess960-9lx-in-2021).

Consider 2 cases where the losing bid gets 15min:

1. Recently in the [2023 champions chess tour Airthings Masters magnus vs hikaru](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gd0Ih0WdY2E) that the bids were Hikaru 8:59 and Magnus 8:58.
2. However in the 2022 ([rapid](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41499/why-was-the-2019-wfrcc-called-slow-rapid-when-its-actually-classical-4515-6)) WFRCC finals between hikaru and nepo, [the winning bid by Nepo was 13min](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41534/what-were-all-the-chess960-armageddon-games-played-in-st-louis-chess-9lx-and-the).

There's a 4 minute gap. **The players seem to want black 31% more in chess than in chess960** because -31% = (9-13)/13.

## III.1. Actually let's do more

[Armageddon: How much more desirable is black in chess than chess960 based on airthings masters 2023 vs 2022 WFRCC?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41586/armageddon-how-much-more-desirable-is-black-in-chess-than-chess960-based-on-air)

It's still around 30%. Average is 12.1458333...min = 12min 8.75sec in chess960 (still 2022 WFRCC) vs 9.3875min = 9min 23.25sec in chess (still 2023 Airthings).