# Armageddon: How much more desirable is black in chess than chess960 based on airthings masters 2023 vs 2022 WFRCC?

Tags: chess-variants, statistics, time-control, chess960, armageddon

All games in question are 15 minutes.

In the 4 armageddon games in the 2022 ([inaugural rapid](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41499/why-was-the-2019-wfrcc-called-slow-rapid-when-its-actually-classical-4515-6), not the *real*, classical) [WFRCC (both qualifiers and final 8)](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41538/armageddon-does-should-white-have-a-lower-advantage-in-chess960-compared-to-c), the Black winning bids are: 13,13,11:10,11:25. Average is 12.1458333...min = 12min 8.75sec.

What were the Black winning bids in in the 2023 Champions Chess Tour Airthings Masters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 4 armageddon games in the 2023 champions chess tour airthings masters the Black winning bids are (approximately)

1. Hikaru vs Wesley So - [9:30](https://lichess.org/broadcast/airthings-masters--division-1/day-2--winners-sf/AQ823XpR/k3soVSU3#4)
2. Gukesh vs Rauf Mamedov - [11](https://lichess.org/broadcast/airthings-masters--division-1/day-2--losers-r1/wruwMAyF/XaRT0PVR#6)
3. Hikaru vs Magnus - [8:58](https://lichess.org/broadcast/airthings-masters--division-1/day-3--winners-final/9rUybzMW)
4. Hikaru vs Wesley So (again) - [8:05](https://lichess.org/broadcast/airthings-masters--division-1/day-4--losers-final/KvSGmoWH/OauNr2c9#4)

Average is 9.3875min = 9min 23.25sec

This is a difference of (9.3875-12.1458333333333)/9.3875 = -0.29383044829 ~ -30%. Black appears to be 30% more desirable.