# Non-linearity in Armageddon bidding: Ostensibly, you give up more time in higher time control

Tags: statistics, time-control, mathematics, armageddon

Note: In the ff I assume everyone bids for [black, not white](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41552/why-would-i-bid-for-white-in-armageddon-in-regular-chess).

## In blitz (below 10min) :

I see often there's a 5min vs 4min predetermined time. No idea if this is fair, but let's pretend arguendo players would really bid around 3:45-4:15 eg in [the 2019 WFRCC and in the 2022 St Louis Chess 9LX](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41534/what-were-all-the-chess960-armageddon-games-played-in-st-louis-chess-9lx-and-the) in the [2022 women's US Chess Championship](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zGO_rm4UStE&t=3773s), Jennifer Yu vs Irina Krush.

- **The ratio of black's time to white's time is 80%** = 4min / 5min.

## In [fast rapid](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41478/how-does-fide-define-slow-rapid-fast-rapid) (10min-32.5min) :

In the 2022 WFRCC and in the 2023 champions chess tour airthings masters, I notice [they bid 9.3min for chess and 12.14min for chess960](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41586/armageddon-how-much-more-desirable-is-black-in-chess-than-chess960-based-on-air).

- In chess960, the ratio is still about 80%. It's 81% = 12.14/15.
- **In chess, the ratio drops to 62%** = 9.3/15.

## In slow rapid (32.5min-[strictly below](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41499/why-was-the-2019-wfrcc-called-slow-rapid-when-its-actually-classical-4515-6) 60min)

(Actually I know of only 1 case.)

[2013 USCC Alejandro Ramirez vs Gata Kamsky](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3Ova9ucsHk) - The bid is 19:45 vs 45min. Since there's a 5 second [increment](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41576/is-armageddon-always-without-increment-should-it-be), this [converts](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41479/time-control-conversion-when-it-comes-to-bonus-time-after-eg-40-moves) to 24:45 vs 50min.

- **The ratio has now dropped to below 50%, i.e. below half.**

**Question**: Ostensibly, you are willing to give up more time in higher time controls. I guess it makes sense intuitively, esp in the reverse way: You are more hesitant to give up time in lower time controls. But I'm not sure how to explain this precisely. **Why are players willing to give up more time in higher time control instead of just that the ratio is maintained throughout any time control?**

Or well maybe it doesn't have to do with armageddon specifically. Maybe in general a game where players have remaining time 3min vs 6min is really different from a game where the same players have remaining time 30min vs 60min?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there are two main reasons for this.

1. The draw rate increases as the time control increases.

From [here](https://www.chess.com/blog/ThomasJEvans/drawing-rates-in-chess-pt1---time-matters) the draw rate in chess for elite chess is roughly ~36% for classical, ~30% for rapid and ~18% for blitz. This gives a larger advantage to black, and therefore a bigger incentive to give up time in order to gain this advantage.

2. The performance drop-off for losing time is less at longer time controls.

Ken Regan shared a model of how much performance of elite players degrade at different time controls on the [Perpetual Chess Podcast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UsEIBzm5msU&t=617s). His model there can be viewed [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/do7pbyh5ay)

He uses the orange line (formula of 338.845\ -\ \frac{1442}{x^{0.283638564}}). This means in order to give up 100 Elo (for example) in classical chess you could give up ~100 minutes out of 165 minutes (60% of your time). In rapid chess, it would be more like: ~14 minutes out of 30 minutes. (45% of your time). In Blitz chess, you would give up roughly 87s out of 5 minutes (~30% of your time)

You would need to give up more Elo to compensate for the increased draws of longer chess

To make these estimates concrete:

- For classical chess with a draw rate of 36%, you would want to give up ~131 Elo. This equates to bidding 52 minutes for a 165 minute game
- For rapid chess with a draw rate of 30%, you would want to give up ~107 Elo. This equates to bidding 13:45 for a 25 minut game.
- For blitz chess with a draw rate of 18% you would want to give up 63 Elo, this equates to bidding 3:57 in a 5 minute game.

There is probably an additional third reason, which is that elite players have a "drawing repertoire" with black where they play more solidly for a draw. This repertoire probably has more force in longer time controls where they can find strong moves if white attempts to complicate. I don't think I'm a good enough player to comment on whether how much this is the case

---

> Maybe in general a game where players have remaining time 3min vs 6min is really different from a game where the same players have remaining time 30min vs 60min?

Yes, it's very different. In 30 vs 60 minutes the performance drop off (in Elo) is ~100 Elo. In 3 vs 6 minutes the performance drop off is more like ~190 Elo.