# Is armageddon more fair if bids aren't 1-time only?

Tags: statistics, time-control, mathematics, armageddon

As pointed out by GeneM [here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/7962/which-side-has-the-advantage-in-an-armageddon-tiebreak-game/8269#8269)

> Armageddon Chess is a *fair* tie-break system only if the two players *bid* for how much time Black should have.

**Question**: But is it actually more fair if the bids are the usual [English auction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_auction) instead of [1-time only](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-price_sealed-bid_auction)?

My guess is yes but they do 1-time only bids for practical reasons like with [plurality voting](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/69965/plurality-voting-advantages). Of course it could be that either 1-time only is actually more fair than bid or somehow, the results will end up the same regardless of the kind of auction.

Consider recently in [2023 champions chess tour Airthings Masters magnus vs hikaru](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gd0Ih0WdY2E), where the bids were Hikaru 8:59 and Magnus 8:58.

2 ways to look at it:

1. I think with 1-time only, they're bidding far lower than what they normally would bid in an English auction - something like they're bidding not *how much they want black* (or white, if you can choose colour) but *how much they don't want their opponent to get black*. I think if they did an English auction, then black would end up with maybe 10-12 minutes.
2. But here, there's only a 1 second difference. Maybe they'd bid even lower. If the bids would continue - let's say the next bid must be at least 10 seconds lower than your opponent's bid - then the might go as low as 6 minutes.

Consider also:

3. If I were to bid exactly 15 minutes because my opponent thinks I'd go as low as 9 minutes. Then I'd trick my opponent to do like 8:30 whereas my opponent wouldn't even have gone lower than 10 minutes otherwise. I think this can be fixed with [Vickrey auction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vickrey_auction) as pointed out [actually by Jim Ratliff in the same](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/7962/which-side-has-the-advantage-in-an-armageddon-tiebreak-game/32583#32583) thread with GeneM.

Comment: What is your mathematical definition of "_fair_"?

Comment: @SecretAgentMan same as GeneM...?

Answer (score 1):

Auction theory says that, under pretty general conditions:

> [A]ll four of the standard single unit auctions have the same expected
> sales price (or seller's revenue).The four standard single unit
> auctions are the English auction, the Dutch auction, first-price
> sealed-bid auction, and the second-price sealed-bid auction.

(See [Revenue Equivalence for One-sided Markets](https://www.econport.org/econport/request?page=man_auctions_revequiv), EconPort. See also [the discussion in Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3987876/revenue-equivalence-in-auction-theory-how-does-an-english-auction-generate-the).)

Here, the “sales price” corresponds to the amount of time on the clock a player is willing to sacrifice to obtain draw odds with the Black pieces rather than full time with the White pieces.

The reason this is achievable in a single round of sealed bids (as is the typical mechanism in Armageddon bidding) is that “truthful revelation” is the equilibrium, and the winner gets the loser’s bid.

Answer (score 0):

Ok actually reading about the [Vickrey auction](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41579/is-armageddon-more-fair-in-vickrey-auction-eg-magnus-hikaru-bid-858-vs-859) made me think of the Jim Ratliff's answer made me think it's LESS fair:

If Hikaru wants to go for as low as 9 minutes, but Magnus wants to go for as low as 6 minutes, then maybe we'd just end up with that the final bid is - let's say there's a minimum of a 10 second difference between bids - Magnus with 8:50. Hikaru won't go lower, and then Magnus has a 3 minute advantage.